# Some messages getting logged multiple times in log4j multi-threading application

Tags: java, multithreading, log4j

In JAVA, suppose I have a multithreaded application which is using log4j and there are more than 1000 threads t1,t2,t3 and so on, running and calling the same logging function passing a message along with thread ID, for instance log.info("info message").

**Here is Filelogger class:**

```
public class FileLogger
{
 private static ConcurrentHashMap<String, AnalyticsLogger> hmap = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, AnalyticsLogger>();
    private static final String DELIM = "|";

    public static class AnalyticsLogger
    {
        private Logger logger;
        private AnalyticsLogger(String name)
        {
            logger = Logger.getLogger(name);
            logger.setAdditivity(false);
        }

        public void stat(String tag, Object map)
        {
            logger.info(tag.toString() + DELIM + map.toString());
        }
    }

    public static AnalyticsLogger getFileLogger(String loggerName)
    {
        AnalyticsLogger aLogger = hmap.get(loggerName);
        if(aLogger == null) {
            hmap.putIfAbsent(loggerName, new AnalyticsLogger(loggerName));
            aLogger = hmap.get(loggerName);
        }
        return aLogger;
    }

}
```

**Instance creation:**

```
//creating object
private static AnalyticsLogger analyticsLogger = FileLogger.getFileLogger("1");
//calling method
analyticsLogger.stat(tag, obj.toJSONString());
```

Note:
1. I used concurrent hashmap to ensure that there should be one and only one instance of a particular logger so whole log messages goes to one place. (Although I think that Logger.getLogger() is thread safe but still using hashmap to be double ensure )

1. **Funny thing is that it happens for some random messages at random time.**
   some messages got logged even more 100 times.

Please help me out

Comment: How do you determine that the multiple logging is the fault of the logger and not that the threads actually are calling the logging method that many times?

Comment: I am sure because exact same message(with time stamp) is logging multiple times and my flow also sends same data to client who is getting this messages once.

Answer (score 0):

Log4J has to be synchronized, otherwise you would see interleaved and garbled log messages in your file. But at least in Logback only appenders are synchronized, not the whole logging message (so computing effective log level, log message, etc. is multi-threaded).

You may also be interested in [AsyncAppender](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/AsyncAppender.html) to queue logging messages in a single, different thread.